# Entity doesn't associate correctly

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have the next relationships:

```
Presupuesto: oneToMany with Revision
Revision: oneToMany with Capitulo
Capitulo: oneToMany with Requisito
Requisito: oneToMany with Articulo
```

I have a form embedded with these entities and 'addTagForm' set. The problem is that when I submit the form, everything is associated correctly except from `Revision` with `Capitulo`, which associates as null.

Below there's the most relevant information about these two entities:

Revision.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo", mappedBy="revision", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $capitulos;

/**
 * @param \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo
 *
 * @return Revision
 */
public function addCapitulo(\CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo)
{
    $capitulo->setRevision($this);
    $this->capitulos[] = $capitulo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo
 */
public function removeCapitulo(\CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo)
{
    $this->capitulos->removeElement($capitulo);
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getCapitulos()
{
    return $this->capitulos;
}
```

Capitulo.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision", inversedBy="capitulos", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="revision_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $revision;

/**
 * @param \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision $revision
 *
 * @return Capitulo
 */
public function setRevision(\CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision $revision = null)
{
    $this->revision = $revision;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision
 */
public function getRevision()
{
    return $this->revision;
}
```

nuevo.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(formulario) }}
//some code..
{% include 'ComercialBundle:Presupuesto:listaRevisiones.html.twig' %}
//some code..
{{ form_end(formulario) }}
```

listaRevisiones.html.twig

```
{% macro information_prototype(revision) %}
    {% if form_errors(revision.total) %}
        {{ form_widget(revision.total, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control totalrevision error'}}) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(revision.total, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control totalrevision'}}) }}
    {% endif %}
    {% include 'ComercialBundle:Presupuesto:listacapitulos.html.twig' %}
{% endmacro %}

<div class="ibox product-box active primerarevision" data-prototype="{{ _self.information_prototype(formulario.revisiones.vars.prototype)|e}}">
{% for revision in formulario.revisiones %}
    {{ _self.information_prototype(revision)}}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I cannot figure out why `revision_id` is null. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you check in your Controller if the data is actually set correctly in the form. So that would be a `var_dump()` of something like: `$form->getData()->getRevisions()->getCapitulos();`.
This way we can figure out if the problem is in the form declaration, or in Doctrine.

Comment: Yes, when i do dump($form->getData()), Capitulo appear, but has its revision attribute null

Answer (score 1):

You work on Revision object which is not owning side of that relation so by default it will not be checked and persisted by Doctrine.

It's important that you work on owning-side entity (one with `JoinColumn`).

Add to your controller (after validating form) this:

```
$capitulo->setRevision($revision);
$em->flush();
```

Read more here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts

Comment: I can not change the relationship, because it must be Revision OneToMany Capitulos

Comment: Then you need manually in controller do `$capitulo->setRevision($revision);` and then flush.

Comment: Right, I did that and it works, but wanted it to be automatic, through the AddTag as the other relationships work, thank!

Comment: If you want to have it automatic then you need work on owning side object in form. You can do it probably also with form or doctrine events.